Updating Request Headers in Django Middleware
Before I start complaining about my problem, I have to admit, that I'm not sure if my approach is the best way to handle my problem. I'm using Nuxt as my Frontend and I want to check/renew the JWT access token if it is expired, but the refresh token is still valid.
Hey,
I'm currently trying to write a middleware in Django, which is responsible for updating the JWT access token. However, the test says that I'm not authorized, even though I've updated the header.
class JWTRefreshMiddleware:

    def __init__(self, get_response):
        self.get_response = get_response

    def __call__(self, request: HttpRequest):
        if request.headers.get("Authorization"):
            try:
                AccessToken(
                    str(request.headers.get("Authorization")).split(" ")[1], verify=True
                )
            except TokenError:
                if refresh_token_cookie := request.COOKIES.get("refresh_token"):
                    try:
                        refresh_token = RefreshToken(refresh_token_cookie, verify=True)
                        user = CustomUser.objects.get(
                            id=refresh_token.payload.get("user_id")
                        )
                        new_access_token = str(AccessToken.for_user(user))


                        request.META["HTTP_AUTHORIZATION"] = (
                            f"Bearer {new_access_token}"
                        )

                    except TokenError:
                        pass

        response: HttpResponse = self.get_response(request)

        return response

The endpoint which I'm trying to call looks like the following:
from ninja_jwt.authentication import JWTAuth

router = Router()

@router.get("/profile", response={200: UserProfileResponse}, auth=JWTAuth())
def get_user_profile(request):
    # Some Code

I've also tried to override request.headers["Authorization"], but...
TypeError: 'HttpHeaders' object does not support item assignment


that's right, request.headers is immutable.

This is an anti-pattern. Auto-updating the access token server-side defeats a portion of the purpose JWT is serving. You're also not sending the new access token back to the client, so every page load would generate a new access token. Might as well use an API key approach instead, it'll be easier to implement the auth and the security considerations will be somewhere between identical to what you're doing now or better. If you want to stick with JWT, either bake a timestamp into the token as a claim so the frontend can check validity before sending any requests, or make a validation endpoint.
